# Removing write protection on a usb drive

Tags: usb-drive, readonly

I have an usb flash-drive that is write protected since a system crash. In the dmesg, the device write protection is first off, then it is turned on.

Here is the dmesg:

```
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 60566016 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2b 00 00 08
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2b 00 80 08
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
EXT4-fs (sdb3): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (sdb3): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
/dev/sdb4: Can't open blockdev
```

Here is the result of the command `hdparm /dev/sdb`:

```
/dev/sdb:
 multcount     =  0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 29573/64/32, sectors = 60566016, start = 0
```

I also ran `badblocks` on /deb/sdb, and it found no bad blocks.

I tryed the command `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` with no success. No more success with hdparm security commands like:

```
hdparm --security-mode m --user-master m --security-unlock p /dev/sdb
```

This command says:

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

`hdparm -I /dev/sdb` gives the following result:

```
/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0
```

Is there a way to turn off write protection, or my usb flash-drive is definitely lost ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely USB has a hardware failure, it happens quite often especially with cheap USB drives. 
There is an extensive answer for your question: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/1028453/1177212

Comment: I have read about some Windows softwares, like AlcorMP, that are able to flash the usb drive and restore factory settings, but it seems there is no software tool for my usb drive. So I validate your answer, my usb drive seems to be lost.

Comment: Your drive is not *lost*: You can "dd_rescue" the contents to a (writable) image, and then repair that image, mount it, and save the files.